# How to use python variable to form SQL CREATE TABLE statement

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, macos

I am creating a python program which ultimately creates an personal SQL database.

The application gathers user data in the form of names(Database, Tables and assoc. columns). Following is test code I am using as a trial.

Problem - my CREATE TABLE process is not working.  Can anyone help me formulate a process that works using the variables I have assigned?

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

```
# Create the starting criteria
root = Tk()
root.title("Build SQL")

def CreateDB():
    my_user = 'root'
    my_host = 'localhost'
    my_pw = 'you sql password here'
    DB_Name = "Test2db"

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=my_user, password=my_pw,
                                  host=my_host)
                                  #database=DB_Name)

    # Create Cursor Instance
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    # Create Databaase
    db = "CREATE DATABASE " + DB_Name
    print(db)
    # db Printout
    # CREATE DATABASE Test2db

    # Merged db works in cursor.execute statement & Creates Database
    cursor.execute(db)

def CreateTable():
    # Variables 
    my_user = 'root'
    my_host = 'localhost'
    my_pw = 'you sql password here'
    DB_Name = "Test2db"

    table1 = "BaseInfo" 

    col1 = "Item INTEGER(10) NOT NULL," 
    colLast = "Ext VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL"""

    # Connector Setup
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user=my_user, password=my_pw,
                                  host=my_host,
                                  database=DB_Name)

    # Create Cursor Instance
    cursor = cnx.cursor()

    # The following lines have work independently (Double Quote & Single Quote)
    # Double Quote Trial
    # cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE BaseInfo (Item INTEGER(10) NOT NULL, Ext VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL)")
    # Single Quote Trial
    # cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE BaseInfo (Item INTEGER(10) NOT NULL, Ext VARChAR(6) NOT NULL)')

    # Merge Variables to make a CREATE TABLE Statement
    tbl1 = '%s (%s %s)' %(table1,col1,colLast)
    print("tbl1 = ", tbl1)
    # tbl1 PRINTOUT
    # BaseInfo (Scott INTEGER(10) NOT NULL, Ext VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL)

    tbl2 = ("CREATE TABLE %s") %(tbl1)
    print("tbl2 = ",(tbl2))
    # tbl2 Printout
    # ("CREATE TABLE BaseInfo (Item INTEGER(10) NOT NULL, Ext VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL)")

    # cursor.execute(tbl2)
    #Error Message Received
    # SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"CREATE TABLE BaseInfo (Scott INTEGER(10) NOT NULL, Ext VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL)")' at line 1

def bldSQL():
     
    CreateDB()
    CreateTable()

bldSQL()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: There seem to be explicit double quotes around `tbl2`, but I don't see where they're coming from.

Comment: I tried your code, and the `tbl2` printout didn't have `()` or `"` around it. Are you sure this is the code you're running?

Comment: I am trying to merge the variables table1, col1 and colLast into an sql statement that generates the table and the columns.  I have tried all sorts of formatting to generate the correct SQL statement.  I have re-run and my terminal output shows '"CREATE TABLE BaseInfo (Item INTEGER(10) NOT NULL, Ext VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL)'.  I just can not get the statement....

Comment: I am trying to make tbl2 = ("CREATE TABLE BaseInfo (Item INTEGER(10) NOT NULL, Ext VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL)").  Then I can do cursor.execute.  My output internal always includes single quotes.  I have tried to strip and replace with no luck.

Comment: I don't see where those extra quotes are coming from in the first place.

Comment: It would only happen if you wrote `tbl2 = '"CREATE TABLE %s"' % (tbl1)`

Comment: @Barmar. If you are out there I do appreciate any information you provide.  Perhaps my code display is inappropriate but the basic objective is to use variables in Python to create a useable SQL syntax to create a table.  If you have a solution I would also appreciate a code sample ie given var1 = name and var2 = age how would you code a adding table name(Table1) to an existing database.

Comment: I understand what you're trying to do. As far as I can tell, the code should work. I don't see where the extra quotes are coming from, I don't see them when I try the code myself.

Comment: could it be the way I am formatting my variables - col1 & colLast?

Comment: I copied your code that formats the strings (without the database or tk calls) and it worked as expected.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/I3XLJA